# Can someone explain how this site does this cool thing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

http://www.spiderball.com/index.php

move your curser around and the background moves around.

Can someone explain how this is done? (what scripting or programming language do they use?) And is there an off the shelf script that can do this for my site?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done with an effect called "parallax" which has been in use by cartoon animators for decades and recently become popular in websites through use of jQuery.

Here is a good demo of the effect: http://dev.jonraasch.com/scrolling-parallax/examples/multi-directional-parallax

And here is a tutorial to show you how to do it: http://jonraasch.com/blog/scrolling-parallax-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 2):

The site uses jquery to find the position of the mouse and move the background accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JavaScript, track the mouse position, and move backgrounds/elements as needed. Basic.